# AudioTrack not streaming thrugh headphones

Tags: android

I've set up an AudioTrack like so:

```
public NoiseThread(byte[] data)
{
    rawData = data; 
    bufferSize = 2* AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize (44000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);

    track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    track.setStereoVolume(volume, volume);
}

public void run() {         
    setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);

    track.play();
    while(!isInterrupted()){
        track.write(rawData, 0, bufferSize);
    }
    track.stop();
}
```

And the sample plays through the speaker as I'd expect. When I plug in headphones, the speaker turns off but the sound comes out of the phone's earpiece and not the headphones. How do I play through headphones?

Comment: A little more experimentation shows that this only happens when I run this through a service. When I launch the thread from an activity it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Many Android devices use a single output thread in the AudioFlinger / audio HAL for all local playback (earpiece, speaker, wired headset/headphones), making different routing of two tracks simultaneously impossible (which is why on many devices the media streams are forcibly muted if a notification is played and you've got a wired headset attached; because otherwise you'd hear the music in the loudspeaker while the notification is played).

On some devices it might be possible to do what you're looking for if you manage to do a **setForceUse(FOR_MEDIA, FORCE_SPEAKER)** and use the MUSIC stream type for the stuff you want to play in the loudspeaker, and the **VOICE_CALL** stream type for the stuff that you want to play in the wired headset.
I'm not sure if there's any way for an application to perform that setForceUse call though. Perhaps you can get at the handleMessage method of the AudioService class through reflection and send it an **MSG_SET_FORCE_USE** message.. I've never tried it myself so it might fail miserably.

Comment: I am only trying to play one single sample. Not trying to do anything clever here. Just trying to do what all other audio applications do, which is play through the wired headset when the wired headset is attached.